# Die or Dice when talking about several at the same time, but individually

Tags: grammar

I am aware that "Die" is the singular and "Dice" is the plural. What I'm trying to figure out is how you refer to one when talking about a groups individual parts.

IE: When talking about a group of people, you use "people". But if talking about the individuals, it's acceptable to use "persons" when talking about each one as an individual. "“Eight persons shared a single room” http://www.worldwidewords.org/articles/people.htm

I'm curious as to whether it would be correct to say something like "All die landed with a 6 on top." or "All die showed a different number".

Comment: This is a question only about singular vs plural, IMO.  *All are* vs *each is*.

Comment: The how about "Six die landed in different places", also, "All" can be both plural AND singular.

Comment: No; 'dice' is an accepted singular also nowadays. //  'Die' and 'dice' are the same lexeme; 'person/s' and 'people' aren't. You rarely have reasonably close synonyms clouding the issue. 'All [the] dice landed ...'.

Comment: The question has nothing to do with *die* or *dice*. It is only about understanding the use of singular and plural subjects with verbs.

Comment: But, seriously, *person/persons* is a special case, as that article with its long explanation should have made clear. There might be a small number of nouns that words analogously but die (dice)/dice is not one of them.

Comment: @Drew, it's not about "understanding the use of singular and plural subjects with verbs" It's literally only about die and dice and whether you CAN use the singular noun when talking about many of that individual noun in some cases. Your example of "all" makes me question whether you're aware that "all" is an indefinite pronoun that can be both singular and plural. The thing I did not consider was that this is not another way to refer to the plural of "die" other than "dice"

Comment: You started from the premise that *die* is plural and *dice* is singular. Given that premise there is no ambiguity at all in what the verb form must be. (Modulo the fact that some people will say anything, of course.)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As you said, "die" is singular. "Persons" isn't, so it's not an analogous case. You can't say "All die landed with a 6 on top" or "All die showed a different number" any more than you can say "Eight person shared a single room” or “All person chose a different number.”

It would be correct to say "Each die landed with a 6 on top" or "Each die showed a different number."

Comment: "Each die landed with a 6 on top." Yes.  Or "All dice landed with 6s on top."